# Drive icons do not display drive contents

Tags: icons, volume, boot, fstab

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu / MS Windows with Ubuntu 22.04 LTE as my 98% main use.  My system has been working fine for many years but recently I have come across a problem which I hope you can help with.

The 2Tb main SSD drive is partitioned into Ubuntu (ext4), MMData (NTFS), Win1064 (NTFS) and the swap file (ext4).  The file 'fstab' was set up to mount MMdata and Win1064 at boot up and these appeared as icons in the tray.  What used to happen was clicking on one of these icons opened a window displaying the folders in that volume.  What happens now is quite different - a window no longer is opened but a very tiny icon appears at the very top of the screen, then disappears a few seconds later.  If I click on the 'Home' icon and click on 'other locations' then the drives display and can be opened as normal.  The contents of the fstab file are shown below:-

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
UUID=1081f505-be04-48bf-af49-2f12db03581d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=6362271167D683DB /media/MMData ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_GB.utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
UUID=60FEBCD6FEBCA626 /media/Win1064 ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_GB.utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=2A90-C867  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

If immediately after boot up I issue the command:-

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
```

then it shows that the MMData and Win1064 volumes are mounted correctly on boot up.

Why do the drive icons in the tray not result in a data window opening anymore?

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Malcolm